# how do I show a php page just once only per user

Tags: php, cookies, session-timeout, session-cookies

Hi I have a php page that I want show it just one time per user.

I think this just might be possible with cookies,session-timeout or session-cookies.

But I'm not sure.

Thanks for your kindness :)

Comment: once per user session or once "for ever"?

Comment: You can just make it so only 1 person per IP address can view it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you answered your own question - by setting a cookie.

```
// check if they've been here, if they haven't set
// a cookie for subsequent visits
if($_COOKIE['beenhere']) { 
    setcookie("beenhere", '1');
}
else {
    // where you want them to go if they've seen this page
    header('Location: http://www.example.com/');
```

For more information:

- http://php.net/setcookie
- http://php.net/header

If you want a single user to -never- see the page again, you must set an expiration for the cookie (see linked page above) as closing the browser will eliminate the cookie as I've set it above.

Comment: This is fine, and I used to use it. But, is there a way to have this for each user? I have a $_SESSION variable, and I would like it so when a newbie user comes in, show a page. One computer can login with multiple SESSIONS, so cookies is not an option. Any help?

Answer (score 2):

To show a page once per-user-session you can try the following

//mypage.php

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['mypage_view'])
{
     $_SESSION['mypage_view'] = 1;   
} else {
     //check if this is not the first time the page has been viewed
     if(isset($_SESSION['mypage_view'])) {
      //not first time redirect
      header('location: google.com');
      session_write_close();
      exit();
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also use sessions

```
if($_SESSION['sessioned_here'] == null) {
    // just been on this page
} else {
    // visited already. get out

}
```

Comment: the session creates a cookie, so in reality you're using a cookie either way

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do that is by getting the visitor's IP. And then you should save it in a database.

You can use this code:

```
    function getUserIP(){
        if (isset($_SERVER["HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP"])) {
            $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] = $_SERVER["HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP"];
            $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'] = $_SERVER["HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP"];
        }
        $client  = @$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
        $forward = @$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
        $remote  = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

        if(filter_var($client, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP)){
            $ip = $client;
        }
        elseif(filter_var($forward, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP)){
            $ip = $forward;
        }else{
            $ip = $remote;
        }
        return $ip;
    } $user_ip = getUserIP();


$rowsnumber = $con->query("SELECT * FROM `visitors` WHERE ip='" . $user_ip . "'")->num_rows;
    $nowdate = date("Y-m-d");
    
    if($rowsnumber == 0){ 
        // First Time Visit
        mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO `visitors` (`visitdate`, `ip`) VALUES ('$nowdate','$user_ip')");
    }else{
        $visitorresualt = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT `visitdate` FROM `visitors` WHERE ip='" . $user_ip . "'");
        $thisvisitor = mysqli_fetch_array($visitorresualt,MYSQLI_NUM);
        
        if($thisvisitor[0] != $nowdate){
            
            //Todays First Visit
            $newvisit = $thisvisitor[1] + 1;
            mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE `visitors` SET `visitdate`='$nowdate' WHERE ip = '" . $user_ip . "'");
        }
        
    }
```