# Restrict web page to be viewed once?

Tags: php, wordpress, cookies

I'm trying to set up a webpage (using wordpress) to display a video that can only be viewed once. After some research it seems that my best option would be to restrict page views via cookies?

For example i have found this code which I feel might do the trick:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['mypage_view'])
{
     $_SESSION['mypage_view'] = 1;   
} else {
     //check if this is not the first time the page has been viewed
     if(isset($_SESSION['mypage_view'])) {
      //not first time redirect
      header('location: google.com');
      session_write_close();
      exit();
     }
}
```

(Source: [how do I show a php page just once only per user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5367357/how-do-i-show-a-php-page-just-once-only-per-user))

How would this be applied within wordpress? or does anyone have any better solutions to achieve this?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: USE SOME DATABASE insertion , because cookies and sessions might be destroyed

Comment: Hello thanks for your quick reply, would you be able to point me in the direction of some more help regarding this? Never used database insertion before?

Answer (score 0):

If this is something where people will actively trying to defeat your security, this won't work. But if people want to view this multiple times, they'll find a way to do it regardless of what you do.
Grab the IP Address

```
$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']
```

Toss it into a file, database, whatever floats your boat

Start the page with

```
$viewedonce = array(); // populate this however you've stored the data
if (in_array ($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $viewedonce)) 
{
header("location: http://redirect.com");
   exit();
}
```

If you would like to combine cookies and IPs, go to town.

Edit:

If all you are after is "AS SOON AS THIS PICTURE IS VIEWED ONCE, BY ANYONE, NO ONE ELSE CAN VIEW IT"

just serve the file, and then delete it

```
unlink($theFile);
```

you can also rename the file and delete it...

```
rename('theFile.jpg', 'derp/theFile.jpg');
```

or copy the file and delete it...

```
copy('theFile.jpg', 'derp/thefile.jpg');
```

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do.

Comment: Hello, yes I realise that if people really want to they can, just trying to make it a little harder/ more awkward. With this method do I need to specify the end users IP? As I would ideally like it to be for any viewer not a specific... Thanks for your response!

Comment: This will take the *reported* end users ip with $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] -- They could change that a variety of ways, but assuming they're just viewing from a computer and up to no funny business, it's fine.

Comment: I would just like it so the page/video can only be viewed once per viewer. There will certainly be multiple people veiwing I just don't want them to easily be able to keep replaying it...

Comment: Then yes, record each *reported* ip address.. Toss it into MySQL (or store it however you'd like) and start the entire page with the if statement. If you want to combine IPs with Cookies, it's just a matter of combining the code for IF the IP is in the array OR the cookie is set.

Comment: Appologies for the extra questions you've been a great help! Will this method still work without knowing the IP addresses? As I have no way of gathering them prior to them veiwing.